# Increment cols in offset function in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a formula : 
    =OFFSET($C$10,FaultAnchor,1,7,1)
I want to increment cols when dragging to the left, what is the corrent code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your rightmost cell is A10, your formula needs to look like this in A10:

```
=OFFSET($C$10,FaultAnchor,count(A10:$A$10),7,1).
```

When you drag it to the left, the count range will increase.
Not sure what "FaultAnchor" refers to though.

Comment: Now its ok, i dragged it left to a total of 338 cell, now my problem is to put each formula in a name. Is there a code to copy each cell formula to a define name? not manually copy paste each to a name manager.

Comment: Probably is, but I don't know it. Would probably best put this as a new question.